# Does `ode45` returns first derivatives value?

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a equation:
`Xdot = A*X + B*U`

I use `ode45` to solve the equation and finding `X` values but does `ode45` returns `Xdot` values? If the answer is yes where does it save them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ode45 does not return the gradient by default, you need to call the function

```
gradient(x,t)
```

Apparently this has been answered in [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/83698-how-to-take-the-derivative-for-the-retained-value-from-ode45).

Hope it helps.